# Difference between PropTypes.exact and PropTypes.shape

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

What's the difference between

```
PropTypes.exact({
  name: PropTypes.string,
  age: PropTypes.number
})
```

vs

```
PropTypes.shape({
  name: PropTypes.string,
  age: PropTypes.number
})
```

I will be glad of any help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically `exact` will give you a warning if your prop object contains extra property not mentioned while declaring it through `PropTypes.exact({ })`.

```
  // An object taking on a particular shape
  optionalObjectWithShape: PropTypes.shape({
    color: PropTypes.string,
    fontSize: PropTypes.number
  }),

  // An object with warnings on extra properties
  optionalObjectWithStrictShape: PropTypes.exact({
    name: PropTypes.string,
    quantity: PropTypes.number
  }),
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes

Comment: What happens with missing properties? In the example, what happens if I don't pass color for the shape, or name for the exact, does it fails?

Comment: Both will give you warning i.e if you do not pass `color` for shape and `name` for exact.

What makes `exact` different is the behaviour on extra properties.
If you pass additional property `age` to both of them, only `exact` will give a warning.

Comment: Thank you, actually if I want the parameters to be required I should use the .isRequired prop, thanks again!

Comment: Yes. `isRequired` helps in maintaining the parameters sanity.
However, if your intention is to fail the compilation, it would not help in that case.
You will get a red colour error in console, but your app will run as usual. 
This is in regards to devlopment in localhost.

Comment: Hi @UtsavPatel, I've been struggling to understand the usage of PropTypes.shape. All looking good on PropTypes.shape, if I attempt to use unmatched type, console warning shows as my expectation. However, if there is extra property or missing property, there is no console warning... Am I mistake anything here, or it is a bug of props-type?

I created a codesandbox to make my question more specifically. https://codesandbox.io/s/clarification-of-prop-types-pfe45

Thank you.

Comment: @Yi-PeiHuang You'll have to use `exact` if you want to see console warning when none of the valid keys are passed.
However, if you have defined props with 2 valid keys, and if you only pass 1 you would not see any error.
Take a look at this example - https://codesandbox.io/s/clarification-of-prop-types-forked-7tts4?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

`PropTypes.shape` just ensures that whatever property that has been provided matches to the type specified.

```
PropTypes.shape({
    name: PropTypes.string,
    age: PropTypes.number
})
```

In the above case, you will get an warning in console only if name is not a string or if age is not a number. On the other hand, it will not throw any warning if we don't provide one or more properties or if an extra property is added.

`name={5} age="Nineteen"` will throw warning.
`name="Sachin" age={50}` will not throw warning.
`name="Sachin"` will not throw warning.
`age={50}` will not throw warning.
`<ComponentName />` will not throw warning.
`name="Sachin" age={50} centuries={100}` **will not throw warning.**

It just ensures there is no mismatch of proptype. It doesn't worry about missing properties or providing additional properties.

---

`PropTypes.exact` is similar to `PropTypes.shape`, only difference is that it will throw warning when an additional property is added. Besides that, it just behaves like `PropTypes.shape`.

While using `PropTypes.exact`

```
PropTypes.exact({
    name: PropTypes.string,
    age: PropTypes.number
})
```

`name={5} age="Nineteen"` will throw warning.
`name="Sachin" age={50}` will not throw warning.
`name="Sachin"` will not throw warning.
`age={50}` will not throw warning.
`<ComponentName />` will not throw warning.
`name="Sachin" age={50} centuries={100}` **will throw warning**.